# How to use the correct type name when using OpenCV cv::Mat.at function

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

It will probably be much easier to describe the situation than describing the problem. I use the following two lines of code in C++ using OpenCV:

```
std::cout << "value near i,j: " << myMat(Rect(i,j,2,2)) << std::endl;
std::cout << "value at i,j: " << myMat.at<double>(i,j) << std::endl;
```

And I get the following results:

```
value near i,j: [34, 42;
  39, 44]
value at i,j: 24
```

I believe the first number in the first value (24) and the value in the second line (34) should be equal. The datatype in myMat should currently be defined as CV_64F. My conclusion is that I am doing something wrong when converting from the OpenCV datatypes to C++ primitive types because I had much worse values when I used CV_16S initially. So what sort of correction do I need to do to access the value in the cv::Mat construction correctly?

P.S: myMat is created and assigned as follows:

```
Mat yourMat, myMat;
[... yourMat is assigned ...]
Sobel(yourMat, myMat, CV_64F, 1, 0, 3, 1, 0, BORDER_DEFAULT);
```

P.S.2: I found a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15778216/why-opencv-mat-at-doesnt-match-original-matrix) but the answer there seems to be only a work-around in assigning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should switch `i,j` in second line: `myMat.at<double>(j,i)`

---

In `myMat(Rect(i,j,2,2))` you're using the `Rect` constructor:

```
x, y, width, height
```

so the top left of your `Rect` is in `(x,y) = (i, j)`. However when you access a value with `.at` you access it with `.at<Tp>(row, col)`, which is the inverse of `(x,y)`, since `row = y` and `col = x`.

So you're effectively reading the value at position `(y, x) = (j, i)`.

---

When working with matrix of type `CV_16U`, you need to access it using `.at<Tp>` with:

- `CV_16UC1` : `m.at<ushort>`
- `CV_16UC2` : `m.at<Vec2w>`
- `CV_16UC3` : `m.at<Vec3w>`
- `CV_16UC4` : `m.at<Vec4w>`

Or you can use:

- `Mat1w`
- `Mat2w`
- `Mat3w`
- `Mat4w`

and access the matrix without `.at`, but just with parenthesis: `m(r,c)`

Comment: Excellent point. I knew the two different parameter orders for Mat.at and Rect but it seems like I didn't manage to tie them together. It turns out that my deduction that it was a type problem (in this case) was wrong and your answer fixed my problem. Just to match with the topic, it would be nice if anyone would care to comment on the type-matching part of the problem: if the CV data type were CV_16S, how would we use the Mat.at command? Because then `myMat.at<double>(j,i)`, `myMat.at<int>(j,i)` or `myMat.at<long>(j,i)` would still give false results.

Comment: Thank you, great work. And with your guidance I have also found [this useful link](http://ninghang.blogspot.com.tr/2012/11/list-of-mat-type-in-opencv.html) with a full list of Mat types in OpenCV and their corresponding C++ types.